# MongoDB indexes for nested Objects

Tags: python, mongodb

So I'm trying to find all my documents that hasn't `images` object, and also count them.

Find within a cursor goes well, as I iterate on the cursor itself so I don't need to wait for fetching, but count takes forever.

I have 11M (11,000,000) records on that collection, it doesn't has any index but `_id` so I know I need to create indexes, but I don't know which indexes I would need...

My document structure has integers and strings, but it contains an `Object`which is `images`.

`name (str) | title (str) | images (Object)`

The `images` object has this structure

`red (int) | green (int) | blue (int) | url (str) | filename (str) | path (str) | product (str)`

And my query is simple

`db.products.find({'images': {'exists': false }}).count()`

I've also tried

`db.products.count({'images': {'exists': false }})`

but as I say, it takes forever to count...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to index images field?

```
db.products.ensureIndex({'images':1})
```

Nested images fields can be accessed using [.(dot) notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation?_ga=1.206987731.1362995012.1410253211)

Comment: I haven't, if I do that It will block DB? I need to run it in background, right?

Comment: By the way the question was to know the appropiate way to create an index for a nested object

Comment: @RobertW.Hunter: you might want to try a solution before complaining. On a test instance, of course. There might be a reason for the answer, albeit not elaborated. ;)

Comment: I didn't complain, sorry if it sound like that. Using that index doesn't solve anything, the count query when a filter is applied never ends, is so slow that never ends...